# How to remove dashboard access (wp-admin) for author but not disable the capabilities?

Tags: wp-admin, author, dashboard, user-access

i want author role can't access wp-admin but still enable the capabilities so they can delete the posts from front end page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in your `functions.php` file or in a plugin-

```
function wpse_253580_prevent_author_access(){
    if( current_user_can( 'author' ) && is_admin() )  {
        // do something here. maybe redirect to homepage
        wp_safe_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_253580_prevent_author_access' );
```

This will check if current user is an **author** and he is trying to access **wp-admin** area. If true, then redirect him to **homepage**.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer by Mukto90 is a little outdated. A better approach would be:

1. Check capabilities instead of role name (`current_user_can` does support a role name but it's not guaranteed to work and these roles can be renamed)
2. Only redirect if it's not doing AJAX
3. exit after safe redirect

Updated answer follows:

```php
add_action( 'admin_init', function(){
    if( (!current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) && current_user_can('edit_posts') && is_admin()) && !wp_doing_ajax() )  {
        // do something here. maybe redirect to homepage
        wp_safe_redirect( get_site_url() );
        exit;
    }
} );
```